# How can you declare an object and invoke its methods from a class defined in a different Project in same solution?

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I am trying to use Microsoft CppUnitTestFramework. I have two separate projects in one solution, one the actual code and the other one is the unit test code. Now I would like to test the "DijkstarImpl" class defined in the first project and I added the path for this class in project Properties->C++->General->AdditionalInclude directories. The test project compiles successfully, but when I run the test I get this error:

Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class DijkstarImpl * UnitTest_FasTrack::UnitTest1::dijkstarImpl" (?dijkstarImpl@UnitTest1@UnitTest_FasTrack@@2PAVDijkstarImpl@@A) C:\working\TestFastTrack\UnitTest_FasTrack\unittest1.obj

Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DijkstarImpl::DijkstarImpl(void)" (??0DijkstarImpl@@QAE@XZ)   C:\working\TestFastTrack\UnitTest_FasTrack\unittest1.obj

The error is the linker error, but I don't know what should I link? It is not a lib file to be included in Properties->Linker->Input.
The following snippet shows the unit test code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "DijkstarImpl.h"
#include "string.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest_FasTrack
{       
TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
{
    static DijkstarImpl*  dijkstarImpl;

public:
    TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(Initialize) 
    {           

        static DijkstarImpl*  UnitTest_FasTrack::UnitTest1::dijkstarImpl;
    }

    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
    {



    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to declare an instance of the variable outside the class, but in the same namespace.

```
namespace UnitTest_FasTrack
{       
  TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
  {
    static DijkstarImpl* dijkstarImpl;

    public:
      TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(Initialize) 
      { 
      }

      TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
      {
      }
  };
  DijkstarImpl *UnitTest1::dijkstarImpl; //declared outside the scope of the class
}
```